# Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers which are not the sum of $8$ or fewer sixth powers of non-negative integers. Is S finite or infinite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of all positive integers which are *not* the sum of $8$ or fewer sixth powers of non-negative integers. Is $S$ finite or infinite?

Google finds that this is a part of the [Waring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem):

> For every $k$, let $g(k)$ be the smallest integer such that every positive integer is the sum of at most $g(k)$ $k$-th powers of non-negative integers, and $G(k)$ the smallest integer such that all but a finite set of positive integers are the sum of at most $G(k)$ such $k$-th powers. So the question is: Is $G(6) \le 8$ or $G(6) \ge 9$?

The Wikipedia article about the Waring problem has a link to a publication claiming that $9 \le G(6) \le 24$. This would mean that the number of integers that are not the sum of eight or fewer sixth powers is infinite, with obvious hope that there is an easy proof.

<sup>I also give [my own answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442485) below.</sup>

Comment: I think it would help other MSE users to have some context for this question. Where does this problem arise and why is it interesting?

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy proof: We can easily show that $n^6 = 0 \mod 9$ if n is a multiple of 3, and $n^6 = 1 \mod 9$ if n is not a multiple of 3. Therefore if any sum of sixth powers equals 0 mod 9, then the number of integers in that sum which are not divisible by 3 is a multiple of nine. Therefore if any sum of 8 or fewer sixth powers is a multiple of 9, then all elements of the sum are multiples of 3.

Each of the numbers 9 <= k <= 63 is not the sum of fewer than k sixth powers. We show that for any such k, $k \cdot 729^n$ is not the sum of eight or fewer sixth powers by induction over n: $k \cdot 729^0$ is clearly not the sum of eight or fewer sixth powers, because the first sixth powers are 0, 1, 64, and 729, so the sum of eight or fewer sixth powers is either <= 8 or >= 64. Now if $k \cdot 729^{n+1}$ is the sum of eight or fewer sixth powers, then all the numbers that were raised to the sixth power are multiples of three because $k \cdot 729^{n+1}$ is a multiple of 9. But that means we can divide all the numbers by 3, and get a solution for $k \cdot 729^n$ which we assumed doesn't exist.

Therefore all numbers of the form $k \cdot 729^n$, n >= 0, 9 <= k <= 63, require 9 or more sixth powers.

A very similar approach shows that infinitely many integers are not the sum of 15 or fewer fourth powers, because $n^4$ = 0 modulo 16 if n is even, and $n^4$ = 1 modulo 16 if n is odd.